# setState new data into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This maybe a silly question, so I apologize in advance.

I have a small array where I iterate it with `this.state.data.map()` and pass the data into inputs. I would like to edit the data in each input and save the new data. Since it's an array, how can I save this new data into the array? Which is the best/smartest practice for this?

[A live example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zlyxjympml)

Here is an example below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
      editMode: false
    };
  }

  handleInput = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    console.log(name);
    console.log(value);

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: {
        ...prevState.data,
        [name]: value
      }
    }));
  };

  handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { data } = this.state;
    console.log(data);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          {!this.state.editMode ? (
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ editMode: true })}>
              edit
            </button>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => this.setState({ editMode: false })}>
                cancel
              </button>
              <button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}>submit</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

        <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.data.map((rule, index) =>
            this.state.editMode ? (
              <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                <input
                  onChange={this.handleInput}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Cars"
                  name={rule}
                  defaultValue={rule}
                  key={index}
                />
              </form>
            ) : (
              <p key={rule}> - {rule} </p>
            )
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Is values are unique in `state.data`? Else every identical value will be replaced with new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to pass the `index` of the currently changed item to the event handler to ensure that you are modifying the correct item on the list.

To do this, change your `handleInput` to accept both the `event` object and `index` of the currently changed item.

```
handleInput = (e, index) => {
  const { data = [] } = this.state;
  let value = e.target.value;
  data[index] = value;
  this.setState({ data: data });
};
```

So you have to changed your input `onChange` handler to this.

```
onChange={(event) => this.handleInput(event, index)}
```

See [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/p780wj6m90)

Comment: Your working example is not working :P. @Ana Liza  Pandac

Comment: @RChohen I forgot to save it.:D

Comment: ahaha it's okay :)

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that, your `data` is an array while in `handleInput` you are assigning it to the `object`.

Second, coming to your problem, I am assuming order of the array is also important.
You should set new value on onchange at the same index the prev. value was.

The following code should work:

```
handleInput = (value, index) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const newData = prevState.data;
    newData[index] = value;
    return {
        data: newData
    };
  });
};
```

And `input element` be like:

```
<input
  onChange={(e) => {this.handleInput(e.target.value, index)}
  type="text"
  placeholder="Cars"
  value={rule}
  key={index}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
handleInput = e => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  let name = [e.target.name];
  console.log(name);
  console.log(value);

   let { data } = this.state;
   data[name]  = value;

    this.setState({data: data});
 };
```